# AngularJS : Filtered data not updating when underlying data changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

I am pretty new to AngularJS and have been working a lot with KnockoutJS bear with me a little as I still haven't quite got my head around when Angular can and cannot track changes.

I am building an app that will have an array of underlying data which initially I will poll and update, but later will improve to push from the server.  All data in the app will then just be transforms or filters based on this data.  So I have a service to fetch the data and to also fetch the commonly filtered versions of the data like so:

```
.factory('Scores', function ($resource, Utils, $q, $interval, $filter) {
    var scoresResource = $resource('http://localhost:8000/scores'),
        scoresData = [];

    $interval(function () {
        scoresResource.query(function (newScores) {
            scoresData.length = 0;
            angular.forEach(newScores, function (dataEntry) {
                scoresData.push(dataEntry);
            });
        })
    }, Utils.TIMES.SHORT);

    return {
        getAll: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            if (scoresData.length > 0) {
                deferred.resolve(scoresData);
            } else {
                scoresResource.query(function (allScores) {
                    scoresData.length = 0;
                    angular.forEach(allScores, function (dataEntry) {
                        scoresData.push(dataEntry);
                    });
                    deferred.resolve(scoresData);
                });
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        },
        getByLeagueName: function(leagueName) {
            return this.getAll().then(function (allScores) {
                return $filter('filter')(allScores, function (score) {
                    return score.League === leagueName;
                })
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And my controller simply fetches the filtered data and adds it to the scope.

```
.controller('LivescoresCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, Leagues, Scores, $interval, Utils) {
    Scores.getByLeagueName($stateParams.leagueName).then(function (scores) {
        $scope.scores = scores;
    });
})
```

But it seems that the filtered data is not automatically updating when the underlying data updates.  I would like to avoid using filters in the view as at times I need to combine data together in ways that I cannot easily achieve.

So I guess my question is why does this not update when the main data updates, and is this a valid approach in an angular world.  I could hit the backend for all variations of the data, but as this is a mobile app and all data is needed in the app at all times I don't really want to make extra requests just to combine or filter the data.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the data on the controller once, using the promise returned by "getByLeagueName". A promise only ever resolves once!

I'm not sure what `ko.computed` really does. But you create a new array inside of `getByLeagueName` that is in no way linked to the original array, by using the filter inside of the service. The new array doesn't "know where it came from"!

It seems you're trying to implement a polling update, which you should do inside the controller, not the service. Think of services as the containers for backend logic, without access to the scope - that's what controllers are for. And as long as you're not working with the scope directly, Angular won't ever update the visible data, because that is the only place that an Angular app gets the displayed data from.

---

The typical Angular way to use filtered data would be: Make the original data, after fetching it, available on the controller. Then use a filter inside of your view (HTML), i.e.: `<div ng-repeat="entry in data | filter: someFilter">`. See [ng-filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter). This way Angular knows when the original data changes, runs the filter on it again, and the UI will update effortlessly.

If you really need to use that filtered data in some other places than the view - and make sure you do - then there's some approaches to that. One is to use the service to notify the controller of data changes: Listen to an event inside the controller via [`$rootScope.$on`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on), and emit that event in the service via [`$rootScope.$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

You can also have a look at [this repository](https://github.com/emmaguo/angular-poller), which takes a promise-based approach to polling data, maybe it works well for your task.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I feared that might be the case.  So as the promise is only resolving once and the array returned from the promise is not the same array as the original one that has the data updated then angular cannot track any changes.

I really don't want to put this filtering/finding in the controller as it will be very common and will then have to be repeated a lot.  Is there anything is angular which is comparable to a ko.computed which will update whenever any of its dependencies are changed?  Or maybe a better way to structure an app like?

Comment: I've added some notes to my answer.